# jquery simulate click, check boxes and call function

Tags: jquery

I have set up a workspace area which represents a blank PDF page where users can select paper size using radio buttons, orientation of landscape or portrait using radio buttons and personal motivation and goal statements using checkboxes. The user checks / unchecks the statement(s) they would like to place on the workspace and are also able to drag and drop them.

When a user changes the orientation I need all the checked statement items to be briefly saved, which I am putting into an array. Then uncheck all the checkboxes of the statements that were chosen to be added (this works) and remove all the statements from the workspace (this does not work). I need to then loop through the array to go back and check the checkboxes (this works) and call the BoardElement function (this does not work) to run the ajax call.

The related code I am using is below, and have tried many suggestion from different posts. The OrientationChange function is what I am using to attempt the save, remove and call to BoardElement which gets the elements.

Thanks.

HTML

```
            <h3>Paper Size</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="paper_size" id="paper_size1" value="8-5x11" checked="checked" />            
            8.5&quot;x11&quot;
            &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="paper_size" id="paper_size2" value="11x17" />            
            11&quot;x17&quot;

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

            <h3>Orientation</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="orientation" id="orientation1" value="l" checked="checked" /> Landscape
                &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="orientation" id="orientation2" value="p" /> Portrait

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

            <h3>Elements</h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="board_element_cb" id="board_ele_0" value="0" /> "Who Am I" Image&nbsp; 
                <input type="checkbox" name="board_element_cb" id="board_ele_1" value="1" /> "Who Am I" Text&nbsp; 
                <input type="checkbox" name="board_element_cb" id="board_ele_2" value="2" /> Mission Statement&nbsp; 
        </fieldset>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready
(
function ()
{
BoardElement = function ()
{
    var elements_array = new Array('wai_img_', 'wai_text_', 'mission_text_', 'affirmation_text_', 'gratitude_text_', 'role_model_');
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        var data_string = 'board_element=' + $(this).val();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get_board_element_ajax.php',
            data: data_string,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $('#board_area').append(html);
                $('.draggable_item').draggable
                ({
                    containment: '#board_area',
                    stack: '#board_area div'
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var checked_value = $(this).val();
        $('.draggable_item').each
        (
        function ()
        {
            if (this.id.indexOf(elements_array[checked_value]) > -1)
            {
                $('#' + this.id).remove();
            }
        });
    }
}
$('input[id^=board_ele_]').click(BoardElement);


// save, remove and get selected board items on orientation change
OrientationChange = function ()
{
    var board_ele_array = new Array();
    // save
    $('input[id^=board_ele_]').each
    (
    function (i)
    {
        if ($('#board_ele_' + i).is(':checked'))
        {
            $('#board_ele_' + i).attr('checked', false);
            board_ele_array.push(i);
            $('#board_ele_' + i).attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
    //for (var j = 0; j < board_ele_array.length; j++)
    //{
    var j = 0;
    function BoardEleCheckbox ()
    {
        if (j < board_ele_array.length)
        {
            $('#board_ele_' + board_ele_array[j]).attr('checked', true);
            //$('#board_ele_' + board_ele_array[j]).click();
            //BoardElement();
            $('#board_ele_' + board_ele_array[j]).click(BoardElement);
            j++;
            setTimeout(BoardEleCheckbox, 1000);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(BoardEleCheckbox, 1000);
    //}
}
$('input[name=orientation]').click(OrientationChange);

});
```

Comment: Can you try rephrasing the intended process (including what is and is not working) as a clear bullet-ed list, and clarifying the language somewhat. It's very confusing to try to follow it in its current form.

Comment: make the question bit clear... its too messy to understand

Comment: pls share the html code as well....

Comment: I've added to the original post and have tried to be a little more clear and have included the HTML. alh84001's response is somewhat working. See my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('#board_ele_' + i).removeAttr('checked');
BoardElement.call($('#board_ele_' + i).get(0));
board_ele_array.push(i);
```

and then:

```
$('#board_ele_' + board_ele_array[j]).attr('checked', 'checked');
BoardElement.call($('#board_ele_' + board_ele_array[j]).get(0));
j++;
setTimeout(BoardEleCheckbox, 1000);
```

Once a handler is assigned to the element, you invoke it with a no-args call, hence `click()`.

**Edit**: http://jsfiddle.net/uxqWv/3/

**Edit 2**: http://jsfiddle.net/uxqWv/7/

When you click on the checkbox, first the state changes and then the handler gets fired. It seems though that when you invoke a `click` handler through jQuery it's the other way around. So the handler thinks that you just checked the button, and adds another board element. To work around this you have to call the handler on the checkbox manually with `call` method of the javascript `Function` object.

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat working. The motivation statements are being removed and then added back as I need them to. However, the checkboxes are not being unchecked and then checked. They are only being unchecked after the call to the BoardElement function.


`alert('uncheck');
    $('#board_ele_' + i).attr('checked', false).click();
    board_ele_array.push(i);`

Comment: `alert(board_ele_array[j]);
   alert('check');
    $('#board_ele_' + board_ele_array[j]).attr('checked', true).click();`

Comment: It seems click() automatically changes the state of a checkbox (which, now that I thik of it, is logical). I updated my answer.

Comment: It was great to see your code working. So, I tried it with my set up, and it didn't work. :(
I decided to put all my jQuery except the form submit along with some CSS in jsFiddle, and you will see the issue I am having.
Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/uxqWv/6/

Comment: I edited my answer. Also, handler for adding and removing elements to the board is flawed. It removes all the elements if you click the second checkbox, and it does nothing when you click deselect other ones. It's because you set id to begin with `draggable_wai_text_` for every element.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is working beautifully! I'll continue testing, but I don't think there will be an issue.
Every element with the id of `draggable_wai_text` was for the purpose of quickly appending some html for jsfiddle.